# Tikz: arrows misplacement

Tags: tikz-arrows, draw

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\newcommand\Square[1]{+(-#1,-#1) rectangle +(#1,#1)}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (2,0) circle (.7);
  \draw[-<-] ($(2,0)+(30:.7)$) to[out=30,in=90] (3.8,0) to[out=-90,in=-30] ($(2,0)+(-30:.7)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is not very satisfying:
[image: look at the arrows]

in particular the arrow is misplaced. How can I get a better result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second approach: The reason that you are having issues is because the center of the arrowhead is somewhat behind the tip. This is because of the way that tikz's arrow algorithm works. Details are available on [page 1016 of the tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#subsection.100.2). Anyways, to fix your problem, I can make modified versions of the standard arrowheads where this offset is set to zero. To do this, I copied the arrow definition code out of `pgfcorearrows.code.tex` and commented out certain offending code that defines the offsets. Here's the result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
% copied with offending section commented out from pgfcorearrows.code.tex 
% lines 1103 to 1157
\pgfarrowsdeclare{tonooffset}{tonooffset}
{
%  \pgfutil@tempdima=-0.84pt%
%  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-1.3\pgflinewidth%
%  \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.21pt%
%  \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.625\pgflinewidth%
%  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
%  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{tonooffset reversed}{tonooffset reversed}
{
  %\pgfutil@tempdima=-0.21pt%
  %\advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-0.475\pgflinewidth%
  %\pgfutil@tempdimb=0.98pt%
  %\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by1.45\pgflinewidth%
  %\pgfarrowsleftextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
  %\pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{+0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{3.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{3.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{3.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position .49 with {\arrow{tonooffset reversed}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\newcommand\Square[1]{+(-#1,-#1) rectangle +(#1,#1)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (2,0) circle (.7);
  \draw[-<-] ($(2,0)+(30:.7)$) to[out=30,in=90] (3.8,0) to[out=-90,in=-30] ($(2,0)+(-30:.7)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

unusual but simple :-) :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) [circle, minimum size=7mm, draw] {};;
  \draw (n1) to [loop, out=30,in=-30, looseness=8] coordinate (l) (n1);
  \draw[->,shorten <=5] ([yshift=-5] l) -- (l);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:** an evolution of above solution. now incorporated in decoration:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
Arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[line width=1pt]},shorten <=5},
decoration = {markings,
              mark=at position .5 with {\draw[Arr,rotate=90] (0,5pt) -- (0,0);}}
                    ]
\node (n1) [circle, minimum size=7mm, draw] {};;
  \draw[postaction={decorate}] (n1) to [loop, out= 30,in=-30, looseness=8] (n1);
  \draw[postaction={decorate}] (n1) to [loop, out= 60,in=120, looseness=8] (n1);
  \draw[postaction={decorate}] (n1) to [loop, out=195,in=255, looseness=8] (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I manually fixed it, but you have already split the loop into two parts, so I don't see much harm.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (2,0) circle (.7);
  \draw ($(2,0)+(30:.7)$) edge[out=30,in=90,->] (3.8,0) (3.8,.014) to[out=-90,in=-30] ($(2,0)+(-30:.7)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The point is that it seems too artificial to adjust that 0.014 offset, and it depends on other parameters of the drawing. I would like to have this set automatically

Comment: Sure, this definitely seems annoying. I think the trick to do what you want is to make a modified version of the arrowhead... I'll see if I can do that.